Concatenate input from columns into rows based on dates
I'm working with a dataset in Google Sheets and need to transform it based on specific conditions. Given the input below, I aim to break down the rows into multiple rows in another sheet if "Yes" is found in the "Break Down Further?" column. Additionally, if the "Date, if different" column is blank, it should use the date from the "Timestamp" column. Finally, the output should be ordered by date.
Note the list will grow:



Timestamp
Date, if different
Total Cost
Purchase Type?
Shop Name
Description
Receipt
Break Down Further?
Cost
Purchase Type?
Description
Break Down Further?
Cost
Purchase Type?
Description




08/04/2024 21:05:14

2054
Cattle
Farmers First
17 Cattle

Yes
893.65
Sheep
3 sheep
Yes
630
Goats
7 goats


08/04/2024 21:06:15

893
Cattle
Outbacks
4 cattle
example.com










08/04/2024 21:08:17
06/04/2024
832
Sheep
Western Out
9 sheep
example.com
Yes
9302
Goats
1000 goat
No






Making this output:
| Date       | Cost   | Category | Company      | Receipt     | Description |
|------------|--------|----------|--------------|-------------|-------------|
| 06/04/2024 | 832    | Sheep    | Western Out  | example.com | 9 sheep     |
| 06/04/2024 | 9302   | Goats    | Western Out  | example.com | 1000 goat   |
| 08/04/2024 | 893    | Cattle   | Outbacks     | example.com | 4 cattle    |
| 08/04/2024 | 2054   | Cattle   | Farmers First|             | 17 Cattle   |
| 08/04/2024 | 893.65 | Sheep    | Farmers First|             | 3 sheep     |
| 08/04/2024 | 630    | Goats    | Farmers First|             | 7 goats     |


I made a EXAMPLE_SHEET so it may be easier to understand


You may try:
=sort(ifna(let(Σ,if(len('Form responses 1'!B2:B),'Form responses 1'!B2:B,int('Form responses 1'!A2:A)), Λ,vstack(hstack(Σ,'Form responses 1'!C2:D,'Form responses 1'!F2:F,'Form responses 1'!E2:E,'Form responses 1'!G2:G), hstack(Σ,'Form responses 1'!I2:K,'Form responses 1'!E2:E,'Form responses 1'!G2:G), hstack(Σ,'Form responses 1'!M2:O,'Form responses 1'!E2:E,'Form responses 1'!G2:G)), filter(choosecols(Λ,1,2,3,5,6,4),index(Λ,,2)<>""))),1,1,5,1,4,1)


